# How can I use group by instead of distinct for this subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery, distinct

I am running this query and its running perfectly fine but I want to use group by instead of distinct

Query which is running perfectly :

```
SELECT VALUE1
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT
(select distinct ORG_CODE 
from
PARAMETERS1 P
where 
P.ORG_ID =LT.LINES) AS VALUE1
FROM 
LINES_TBL     LT)
```

query which I want to run but giving me an error :

```
SELECT VALUE1
FROM 
(SELECT 
(select distinct ORG_CODE 
from
PARAMETERS1 P
where 
P.ORG_ID =LT.LINES) AS VALUE1
FROM 
LINES_TBL        LT
GROUP BY VALUE1)
```

error:

> Not a group by function

Comment: What's wrong with your working query?

Comment: yes I want to replace distinct logic with group by ,there are multiple subqueries like this and I want to replace them

Comment: Start with removing all redundant subquery nesting.

Comment: Why do you want to replace distinct logic with group by?

Comment: I want to use group by because its giving me performance issue

Comment: It does? Are you sure? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle dbms

Comment: I'm not an Oracle guy, but I've never heard of the performance difference you're expecting. I'd recommend writing clear and simple SQL, it's less error prone and easier to maintain.

Comment: @jarlh GroupBy can be better than Distinct in Oracle. I always use GroupBy instead of Distinct in Oracle. About the problem, well to use group by, you need same column in select. Basically, the inner query should be converted like this SELECT 
  VALUE1 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT (
        select 
          ORG_CODE 
        from 
          PARAMETERS1 P 
        where 
          P.ORG_ID = LT.LINES
         group by org_code
      ) AS VALUE1 
    FROM 
      LINES_TBL LT
  )
For second distinct, you should also specify the column.

Comment: @ahmetgül This sounds like rumors produced by unknown source, like `decode` vs `case`. Please provide any evidence that `group by` is faster than `distinct`

Answer (score 1):

You need an aggregate function when you're using `GROUP BY`, your query with it will be something among the lines of:

```
SELECT value1
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(1), p1.org_code AS value1
          FROM parameters1 p1
               INNER JOIN lines lt ON p.org_id = lt.lines
         GROUP BY p1.org_code);
```

If you're concerned about performance, actually the best performance for this query should be with this version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.org_code
  FROM parameters1 p1
       INNER JOIN lines lt ON p.org_id = lt.lines;
```

(just use joins)